# Is it possible to get folder size by logparser?

Tags: size, directory, logparser

I tried the following command but it only gives size when files are encountered, it dosent provide folder size:

```
LogParser "SELECT Path, sum(Size) FROM D:\my_vault\*.*  GROUP BY Path" -i:FS -o:NAT -rtp:-1 -e:1 -recurse:0
```

The folder structure is like :  On D:\  Drive there is a folder by name "my_vault" the folder contains 8 different folders inside like folder01, folder02, folder03....folder08.

I am interested to get the folder size of my_vault and individual folders inside my_vault i.e folder01, folder02, folder03..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the EXTRACT_PREFIX function as follows:

```
SELECT EXTRACT_PREFIX(Path, 1, '\\') AS Folder, SUM(Size) FROM D:\my_vault\*.*  GROUP BY Folder
```

This will group by all files by the first two levels (e.g. D:\MyVault).

Make sure you also specify `-recurse -1`!

Comment: Thats Perfect !  Works like charm!  Will it be possible to get list of subfolders and their size too for e.g.  individual folders inside my_vault i.e folder01, folder02, folder03..?

Comment: Of course, just use EXTRACT_PREFIX(Path, 2, '\\') and you have all the level-3 folders.